# xhr.status and xhr.readyState is 0

Tags: javascript, file-upload, jquery-html5uploader

I'm working with HTML5 multiple file uploader. For some purpose I'm queuing the requests into a JavaScript array and I'm trying with two approaches here, one is, sending all the requests by a loop using a for loop and the next approach is like starting the next request after the previous request got finished. Here is the code,

```
    function processUploads(i)
{
    if(typeof(i)=="undefined")
        return;

    if(i==0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            xhrQ[i].open("POST",FUurl,true);
            xhrQ[i].send(fdQ[i]);
            xhrQ[i].onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhrQ[i].readyState == 4 && xhrQ[i].status == 200) {                
                    uploadComplete(xhrQ[i],i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        xhrQ[i].open("POST",FUurl,true);
        xhrQ[i].send(fdQ[i]);
        xhrQ[i].onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhrQ[i].readyState == 4 && xhrQ[i].status == 200) {                
                uploadComplete(xhrQ[i],i);
            }
        }
    }
}

function uploadComplete(xhr,i)
{
    //processUploads(i+1);
    var responseJSON = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');
    var upldrID = responseJSON.data.queueId;

    var fileProgElem = $("#file_content").find("div[file-count="+upldrID+"]");
    fileProgElem.attr("upload","finished");
    fileProgElem.find("input[id=asset_id]").val(responseJSON.data.asset_id);

    if(typeof(responseJSON)=="undefined") {
        return;
    }

    $("#bar"+upldrID).css("width: 100%");
    $("#progress_text"+upldrID).addClass("hide");
    $("#progress_bar"+upldrID).html("Upload Complete!");

    var pagename = $("#pagename").attr('value');

    var cover_art = "<img src='"+responseJSON.data.thumb_location+"' alt='"+$.trim($("#file_name"+upldrID).html())+"' />";
    $("#cover_art"+upldrID).html(cover_art);

    //Hide the cross icon and enable the save 
    var action_divs = '<div id="done'+upldrID+'" class="hide enable">'
            +'<a id="delete_file_'+upldrID+'" onclick="saveWorkspaceFileDetails(\''+responseJSON.data.project_id+'\',\''+responseJSON.data.asset_id+'\',\''+upldrID+'\',\''+responseJSON.data.file_name+'\',\''+responseJSON.data.size+'\',\'delete\',\''+pagename+'\')">'
            +'<i class="tl-icon-20-close-gray"></i>'
            +'</a>'
            +'</div>';

    $("#cancel_upload"+upldrID).append(action_divs);

    $("#progress_cancel"+upldrID).addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
    $("#done"+upldrID).addClass("show").removeClass("hide");        

    //To show the post and cancel button
    $("#submitFileUpload").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

    //Updating the title with the default value of file_name
    var file_title =  $.trim($("#file[file-count='"+upldrID+"']").find("#file_title").val());
    if (file_title == "" && file_title != undefined){
        $("#file[file-count='"+upldrID+"']").find("#file_title").val(responseJSON.data.file_name);
    }

    //For other category we need to enable the dropdown     
    if(responseJSON.data.category_id=='999')
    {
        $("#select_category"+upldrID).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    }

            //totSelFiles is a number of selected files that i sets as a global variable
    if(i<(totSelFiles-1))
    {
        processUploads(i+1);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

But the problem is i'm getting the readyState and status as 0 in the `if` loop. But the file is getting uploaded to the server and the else condition is also working well if i only enable that block. So what could be the problem. I'm greatly confused. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the closure you create with the anonymous function you use for onreadystatechange. It will have access to the value of `i`, but not from the time of creation of the closure but rather from the time of its execution. At that point of time `i` is always 4 and `xhrQ[i]` will not refer to the correct object. Use `this` instead

```
xhrQ[i].onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

   }
}
```

The problem is that you want to continue with the index `i` inside the uploadComplete() function. For this you might need to create another inner closure with an immediately executing function that will create a local copy of the current index.

```
xhrQ[i].onreadystatechange = (function(_innerI) {
   var that = this;
   return function() {
      if(that.readyState == 4 && that.status == 200) {
         uploadComplete(that, _innerI);
      }
   }
})(i);
```